# how to plot ridgeplots in R?

Tags: r

I tried to do ridge plots for some data, It looks good. for some of them I'm unable to generate.
it says "Picking joint bandwidth of NaN" plots looks blank.
Can some one, help me how to plot for this data.

```
ID                      Description setSize enrichmentScore        NES      pvalue    p.adjust    qvalues rank                    leading_edge
dre04068 dre04068           FoxO signaling pathway       2      -0.9642857 -1.6730549 0.007702612 0.007702612 0.01216202    4 tags=100%, list=13%, signal=93%
dre04218 dre04218              Cellular senescence       2      -0.9642857 -1.6730549 0.007702612 0.007702612 0.01216202    4 tags=100%, list=13%, signal=93%
dre04510 dre04510                   Focal adhesion       2      -0.9642857 -1.6730549 0.007702612 0.007702612 0.01216202    4 tags=100%, list=13%, signal=93%
dre04810 dre04810 Regulation of actin cytoskeleton       2      -0.9642857 -1.6730549 0.007702612 0.007702612 0.01216202    4 tags=100%, list=13%, signal=93%
dre04144 dre04144                      Endocytosis       2      -0.6785714 -1.1773349 0.265740121 0.265740121 0.33567173   12 tags=100%, list=40%, signal=64%
dre00562 dre00562    Inositol phosphate metabolism       2      -0.5714286 -0.9914399 0.514567984 0.514567984 0.40483661   15 tags=100%, list=50%, signal=54%
         core_enrichment
dre04068          494532
dre04218          494532
dre04510          798876
dre04810          798876
dre04144          798876
dre00562          798876
```

ridgeplot(df)

[image: Ridgeplot]

Comment: I haven't used `ridgeplot`, but another option is the [`ggridges` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html), which is a ggplot2 extension.

Comment: I tried, doesn't work generating same blank plot.